# TouchableOpacity effect on Text

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want my Menu  text  to have the same effect that TouchableOpacity does on touch.And open a new screen

```html
***Settings.js***

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View,TextInput} from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity,FlatList,ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

export default function App(){
    const[menu,menupeople]=useState([
        {name:'My Account',key:1},
        {name:'Notification Settings',key:2},
        {name:'Clear Cache',key:3},
        {name:'Legal Information',key:4},
        {name:'Rate App Tak',key:5},
        {name:'Version',key:6},
        {name:'About',key:7},
    ])
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <ScrollView>
            {menu.map((item)=>{
                return(
               <View
               key={item.key}
               >
                   <Text style={styles.item}
                   >{item.name}</Text>
             </View>
                )
            })}
            
          

          
        
            </ScrollView> 
        </View>
    )
    
}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        paddingTop:40,
        paddingHorizontal:20,
        alignItems:'center'
    }
})
```

Is there any way to do this i am first time applying  touchable opacity to a menu of items and each of them opens a new screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the touchableopacity instead of the View to wrap the menu item like below

```
 {menu.map((item)=>{
                return(
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>alert(item.name)}
               key={item.key}
               >
                   <Text style={styles.item}
                   >{item.name}</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
                )
            })}
```

Here I've put an alert you can change it to your navigation code.

And please import the TouchableOpacity from react native

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
```

Comment: thankyou can you guide me one more thing the menu item pressed should open a new window how do i do that

Comment: you can change this to onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('screen name')}, if you are using react navigation